# Need to redirect last part of url using htaccess with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters

#RewriteRule #htaccess
I have a url for eg: [www.example.com/path1/path2/pdfname.pdf](http://www.example.com/path1/path2/pdfname.pdf). i need to redirect this url to another with the pdf name without pdf extension like(pdfname). Redirect Url should be  [www.example.com/path3/viewpdf.php?param=pdfname](http://www.example.com/path3/viewpdf.php?param=pdfname).
Would appreciate your help, Thanks.

Comment: Looks like this should be an internal “rewrite”, rather than an external “redirect”? So, this is for literally any “.pdf” request within “/path1/path2/“?

Comment: You’ve specifically added the “php” tag back (after it was removed with a 3rd party edit), although this doesn’t appear to have anything to do with PHP? How is this a PHP question?

Comment: The first url is path of a pdf file. Second one is the path for processing and viewing pdf. That is a php file. I have to use the php file and get params through url after redirect. I think a php developer can help.

Comment: And "path1", "path2" and "path3" are all fixed, literal strings?

Comment: yes they are fixed strings denoting inner paths.

Comment: _"That is a php file. I have to use the php file and get params through url after redirect. I think a php developer can help."_ - that might perhaps be, but so can possibly people developing in a multitude of other server-side languages. This does not justify the use of the tag here, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "path1", "path2" and "path3" are all fixed, literal strings that probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?path1/path2/(.+)\.pdf$ /path3/viewpdf.php?param=$1 [L]
```

This keeps the URL visible in the browser unchanged, which usually is what is desired.

That rule will work likewise in the central http server's host configuration (which usually is preferred) or, if you do not have access to that, in a *distributed* configuration file (often called ".htaccess"). In the later case that file needs to be readable by the http server process and it has to be located in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of the processing http server's host.

---

If instead of an internal rewrite you really want to *redirect* the request (so change the URL actually visible in the browser), then that variant should do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?path1/path2/(.+)\.pdf$ /path3/viewpdf.php?param=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Again no domain name (http host name) or protocol scheme has to be specified if they stay the same. The same hints as above apply.

Comment: What about the domain names. Do we don't need to add it on rule or conditions. www.example.com/

Comment: This is a rule implementing an internal rewrite. Since it is internal to the http server's host there is not need to handle a domain name (actully a host name). That is how I understood your question. I assume the http host is the same for the incoming request and what it should get rewritten to.

Comment: This is working. Thank you. What if we have different paths for path2. Sometimes it is path2, sometimes it is path5. for eg:  www.example.com/path1/path7/pdfname.pdf. Are we able to do that?

Comment: Sure, either you use amatching pattern naming all possible paths in a logical OR , or you use a separate rule for each path, or you implement a wild card matching, if you are not actually interested in specific paths.

Comment: what will we do if path1 is (undrscore)path1. that is  www.example.com/_path1/path2/pdfname.pdf. path name starting on underscore (_)

Comment: Well, you change the matching pattern in the rewrite rule and add that underscore. If you want to make that underscore optional, then add it as optional: `^/?_?path1/path2/(.+)\.pdf$`

Comment: The `RewriteRule` directive as implemented by the apache rewriting module uses "regular expressions" as matching engine. Regular expressions are an absolute standard for IT. If you operate a web service then there is no around you learning the basics of the tools you are actually using. You cannot simply trust blindly to things you copy and paste. So I would suggest you start by taking a look into the documentation of the rewriting module (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and into a beginners tutorial about regular expressions.